# Working with raster files of very large size

Tags: python, raster

I am generalist web developer with zero GIS experience, and I have a GIS-related question.

I have some raster data that I am trying to expose to users in form of a tile API. The user provides the x/y coordinates and the zoom level, and I return the PNG tile from the raster dataset.

The raster data is very simple: it's `(x, y, d)` tuples, where `x` and `y` are grid coordinates, and `d` is an integer. I store these data as memory-mapped numpy files, where each file corresponds to a single complete dataset. The datasets are independent from each other, and range in size from 5,000^2 to 150,000^2 "pixels".

My prototype web API server (written in Python) is also pretty straightforward:

The caller of the API can specify the dataset, the x/y/zoom parameters, and an optional filter range for `d`. When a request for a tile comes in, the Python server loads the dataset (the numpy file) into RAM, crops out the piece it needs for the tile, filters the data, downsamples it, converts it into a PNG, and then sends the PNG to the user.

The dataset, once it is loaded, is retained in RAM until the server shuts down. If the server happens to run out of RAM (because too many datasets are concurrently loaded), it frees up memory by unloading the least-frequently used dataset.

This setup has worked great for smaller datasets (<1Gb) that don't push the limits of my test box which has 128Gb RAM.

However, I am now trying to scale this architecture to handle arbitrarily large raster datasets. The datasets I am working with now are 90Gb each. I am finding that if I try to request tiles from 2 different 90Gb datasets at once, the server spends most of its time loading/unloading the data. Server response times go from tens of milliseconds to seconds. Imagine using google maps and having to wait 10+ seconds for tiles to load.

Which finally brings me to my question: I assume this is a well-understood problem in the GIS space. How do you serve tiles from terabyte-sized raster datasets to multiple users concurrently?

I am trying to get myself familiar with the problem space, so I am looking for suggestions on what to read. What are some good books or courses?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly; I'd look into using [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/). It's a tiling service. They are very popular.

Comment: If you've already got a big investment in existing code and can't swap out to a proper tiled API, look into not reading the entire dataset into RAM. I mean this is specifically what [`numpy.memmap`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) files are for. You'll need to calculate row & col offsets from the x & y coordinates and read just that bit in (look into affine transforms).

Comment: Another option if rolling your own, store your data as cloud-optimised geotiff, use rasterio to read only the [required window](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.windows.html#rasterio.windows.from_bounds). You can even [downsample](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html) as you read.

Comment: This sounds like a WMTS or TMS server and there are plenty of options out there to solve this problem

Comment: The arbitrary filter on `d` makes this problem harder. Most tiling services make very heavy use of caching, and are consequently not that dynamic. You may consider so-called "data tiles", perhaps using RGB encoding, to allow _client side_ filtering of data (downsampled as appropriate for the requested z), which would give you a caching opportunity. See for example https://github.com/syncpoint/terrain-rgb https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/reference/mapbox-terrain-rgb-v1/ Once you can cache, you can seed the cache independently of user requests, to improve the UX.

Comment: @alphabetasoup Yes, in addition to filtering on `d`, the client wants `d` itself to be dynamically computed. The `d` that they gave me is an average of several numbers in an `(x, y)` cell - `{d1, ..., dn}`. They want to be able to dynamically derive `d` using other functions - mode of `d`, median of `d`, etc. This problem is very intractable.